# how to implement Linq to Entities IQueryable TakeWhile() functionality

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Today while working with LINQ, I leanrnt that TakeWhile() is not supported for LINQ to entities, is there any efficient way to implement such a functionality? The use case I have is as below -

> I have an Employee entity, and I have sorted the entity by Name, now I want to fetch the records from this IQueryable till the time (EmployeeID = 123)

Something like this -

```
IQueryable<Employee> employees = ObjectContext.Employees
          .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
          .TakeWhile(a => a.EmployeeId != 123)
```

However in above code the TakeWhile is not supported for Linq to Entities so it throws an error.

---

I am trying with below approach, Please let me know if anyone has better and efficient aproach:

- Fetch first X records,
- check if the required EmployeeId is part of it,

  - if not then fetch the next set of X records
  - and Concat them with previous set
  - and check if the EmployeeID is part of it again,
  - break the loop when the matching EmployeeId is found in the set of X records..

Comment: What is the sense of this query? Should it be `.Where(a => a.Id < 123)`?

Comment: Why are you ordering by name, but taking by id?

Comment: actually I am writing a lazy loading kind of logic and while loading the list after log off and log-in, I want to load the numder of items till the position of selected item from list and rest of the items wwould retrieved as part of Lazy load...

Comment: If you append `.AsEnumerable()` after the `OrderBy` it will work but execute the `TakeWhile` in code instead of the DB.

Comment: hmmm.. but in this case it would fetch all the records from employee table.. any other much efficient way ?

Comment: @Harshal If possible use `Take(x)` perhaps in combination with `Skip(x)` it is supported by the provider.

Comment: What SQL would you expect this to generate?

Comment: I dont hve SQL solution for it too, but just to reiterate the problem in SQL terms, I have Employee table, then I order by the employee table with Name and from ordered records I want to fetch records till the record having Id as 123. Sorting is custom now it is not NAme, but it can be configured to sort on any other column of table

Comment: Hi Magnus, sorry may be i dint get it, but can you please elaborate how can I fit in Take(x) and Skip(x) in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't sort by `Name`, but store somewhere `Id`. May be, this will help:

```
// eager loading of employees, which name is less or equal, than stored name:
ObjectContext.Employees.Where(a => a.Name.CompareTo(storedName) < 0 || a.Name.CompareTo(storedName) == 0)

// lazy loading the rest of employees:
ObjectContext.Employees.Where(a => a.Name.CompareTo(storedName) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `TakeWhile()` equivalent in SQL so you'll have to do that step in memory.  You can force the SQL to be executed by casting the `IQueryable<>` to an `IEnumerable<>` prior to adding the filters that don't have SQL equivalents.

```
var employees = ObjectContext.Employees
      .OrderBy(a => a.Name)
      .AsEnumerable()  // filters after this point will be done in memory on each record
      .TakeWhile(a => a.EmployeeId != 123)
```